# Joomla 1.5 with Postgresql 8.4

Tags: configuration, postgresql, joomla

can anybody guide me to get to work Joomla 1.5.X with a postgres 8.4 database ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql is not supported by Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 1.5 has no support for PostgreSQl, only MySQL.

PostgreSQL support has been started since Joomla 3.0.

[This](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase) may help.